# how to apply width of image in HTML5 canvas via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my script:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    resourceCache[url] = img;
    readyCallbacks.forEach(function(func) {
         func();
    }
};
```

This script binds images into a canvas. I want to know how to set width for the image. I couldn't understand the meaning of **readyCallbacks.forEach(function(func) { func(); }**

**Full code:**

```
(function() {
var resourceCache = {};
var loading = [];
var readyCallbacks = [];

// Load an image url or an array of image urls
function load(urlOrArr) {
    if(urlOrArr instanceof Array) {
        urlOrArr.forEach(function(url) {
            _load(url);
        });
    }
    else {
        _load(urlOrArr);
    }
}

function _load(url) {
    if(resourceCache[url]) {
        return resourceCache[url];
    }
    else {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            //img["width"] = "101";
            resourceCache[url] = img;

            if(isReady()) {
                readyCallbacks.forEach(function(func) {
                    func();
                });
            }
        };
        resourceCache[url] = false;
        img.src = url;
    }
}

function get(url) {
    return resourceCache[url];
}

function isReady() {
    var ready = true;
    for(var k in resourceCache) {
        if(resourceCache.hasOwnProperty(k) &&
           !resourceCache[k]) {
            ready = false;
        }
    }
    return ready;
}

function onReady(func) {
    readyCallbacks.push(func);
}

window.resources = { 
    load: load,
    get: get,
    onReady: onReady,
    isReady: isReady
};
})();
```

Comment: Try `canvas.width=img.width`

Comment: I would like to know the purpose of "forEach" & "func()" here.

Comment: Provided code is incomplete. Kindly provide complete code to understand..

Comment: I've add the complete script @RayonDabre

Comment: //element.css('width', '100px'); try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/evq6ac0e/2/

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();

//img.src = URL here;

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  c.width = img.width;
  c.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
};
```

Just target your canvas and set the width and height to the image, if you just want to set the width then remove the line `c.height = img.height;` and vice-versa for height

### Part 2

As far as explaining what `readyCallbacks.forEach(function(func) { func(); }` does: it simply iterates the array of functions and calls each function in the array. A callback function gets added to `readyCallbacks` each time `onReady(func)` is called.

The upshot of all this is that the code waits for all images to be loaded before calling all the functions registered via `onRead(func)`

jsFiddle (with comments added) : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/arkjge2o/

```
(function() {
  var resourceCache = {};
  var loading = [];
  var readyCallbacks = [];

  // Load an image url or an array of image urls
  function load(urlOrArr) {
    if (urlOrArr instanceof Array) {
      urlOrArr.forEach(function(url) {
        _load(url);
      });
    } else {
      _load(urlOrArr);
    }
  }

  function _load(url) {
    if (resourceCache[url]) {
      return resourceCache[url];
    } else {

      // Create a new img variable
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
        // Store the new image object
        resourceCache[url] = img;

        // Check to see if all images are loaded
        if (isReady()) {
          // Calls all the callbacks in the array
          readyCallbacks.forEach(function(func) {
            func();
          });
        }
      };

      resourceCache[url] = false;

      // Start the image loading
      img.src = url;
    }
  }

  function get(url) {
    return resourceCache[url];
  }

  function isReady() {
    var ready = true;
    // For each image inside of resourceCache
    for (var k in resourceCache) {
    // See if any of the images is not an image
    // resourceCache.hasOwnProperty(k) will always return true
      if (/*resourceCache.hasOwnProperty(k) &&*/
        !resourceCache[k]) {
        ready = false;
      }
    }
    return ready;
  }

  function onReady(func) {
    readyCallbacks.push(func);
  }

  window.resources = {
    load: load,
    get: get,
    onReady: onReady,
    isReady: isReady
  };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Canvas.
But I couldn't understand what's happening inside img.load function in my code. And I don't find the ctx.fillRect() function call in my code. Still it loads images into Canvas

Comment: @VelMuruganS I have updated my answer with more details.

Comment: Your fiddle explains the code clearly. Thanks for your time @Canvas

Answer (score 0):

Try using dot syntax to set the dimensions of the image and adding px to the end of your value string, as in the example below:

```js
function _load(url) {
    if(resourceCache[url]) {
        return resourceCache[url];
    }
    else {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            img.width = "101px";
            resourceCache[url] = img;

            if(isReady()) {
                readyCallbacks.forEach(function(func) {
                    func();
                });
            }
        };
        resourceCache[url] = false;
        img.src = url;
    }
}
```